# Can an 'Unwind Segue' work between two storyboards connected by a storyboard reference?

Tags: ios9, uistoryboard, xcode7

In iOS 9, storyboards can be connected by a 'storyboard reference' that links to a second storyboard by adding a storyboard reference and setting the 'referenced ID' to the name of another storyboard file.

Is it possible to set up an unwind segue in the second file that unwinds to a scene in the first file? If so, what steps are involved, either in Interface Builder or in code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from your storyboard reference, create a new storyboard reference that will be a reference back to your "Main" storyboard. Make sure you set your Storyboard Identifier on your main as well.

You will now have a "Main Scene" reference with all you Exits now available. You can now create unwind segues as you normally would. Ctrl-drag from your controller to the `Exit` marker on the Main Scene and you will be able to select the desired exit.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I didn't have to make a storyboard reference back from the 2nd storyboard to the first as Ryan laid out. For me, in my second storyboard I could Control-drag from a viewcontroller to its own exit, and the unwind segue that I had specified in a viewcontroller class consumed in the **first** storyboard appeared. So I just selected that to create a new exit segue with an identifier, and called performSegueWithIdentifier: on it in code. Worked fine.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Nothing happens when I programmatically call the performSegueWithIdentifier. Do you know what might be happening?

Comment: Is it related to how we initiate the navigation to the first screen in the second storyboard? i.e.: Switch or Modal?

Comment: Right click on from VC's own Exit, select the unwind method previously defined, drag to from VC.

Answer (score 7):

**1) Add this method to your MainViewController**
`// NEEDED! Do not delete!
@IBAction func unwindToMasterViewController(_ segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {
  // Do nothing
}`
**2) In the Main storyboard, right-click on the Exit segue** of the referenced storyboard and select `unwindToMasterViewController`

[image: Interface Builder]

**3) Give the exit segue a name** to reference it in code

[image: Attributes Inspector]

**4) Call your exit segue from code**